# Can the 5+ and 4+ oxidation state of Vanadium ion exist independently?

Tags: redox, transition-metals, reduction-potential

From my class text book:

> The oxidation states of Vanadium ions 5+ and 4+ are shown in the compounds $\ce{VO2^{+}}$ and $\ce{VO^{2+}}$  respectively, whereas $\ce{V^{3+}}$ and $\ce{V^{2+}}$ are shown like this in the redox reaction (reduction half equation).

Why is this? cannot $\ce{V^{5+}}$ and $\ce{V^{4+}}$ exist indepepently as ions like $\ce{V^{3+}}$ and $\ce{V^{2+}}$ (when measuring the reduction potential)?

Answer (score 1):

When an atom $M$ looses one or more electrons, it becomes positively charged and becomes the ion ${M^{z+}}$. In aqueous solution this positive charge attracts the unused doublets of the Oxygen atom from $H_2O$, and it repells the proton of $H^+$.

If $Z$ = $1$, the ion $M^+$ attracts several molecules water around it, and it makes a Debye layer of oriented $H_2O$ molecules around the ion, and no chemical changes.

If $Z = 2$, the attraction is strong enough to repell one proton $H^+$ from one of the molecules adsorbed around the $Z^{2+}$ ion. The solution becomes a little bit acidic, and the $M^{2+}$ion is partially hydrolyzed into the ion [${M(OH)]^+}$. It is an equilibrium :$$M^{2+} + H_2O \ce{<=>}[M(OH)]^+  +  H^+$$

If $Z = 3$, the attraction between $Z^{3+}$ and water is strong enough to at least transform all $M^{3+}$ions into $[M(OH)]^{2+}$, and part of them to [$M(OH)_2]^+$ with the two reactions :
$$M^{3+} + H_2O\ce{->}   [M(OH)]^{2+}  +  H^+$$
$$[M(OH)]^{2+} + H_2O \ce{<=>} [M(OH)_2]^+  +  H^+$$
This is the case if $M^{3+}$ is $Al^{3+}$ or $Fe^{3+}$

If $Z = 4$, all ions $M^{4+}$ are at least hydrolyzed into $[M(OH)_3]^+$ and even into $M(OH)_4$, according to :  $$M^{4+} + 4 H_2O \ce{->}M(OH)_4  +  4 H^+$$It should be mentioned that $M(OH)_4$ has a tendency to loose water and produce a structure that has acidic properties. So it is often presented under the formula $H_4MO_4$ or $H_2MO_3$. That is the case with $M = Si$. Silicic acid is often presented as $H_4SiO_4$ or $H_2SiO_3$

With Vanadium $V^{4+}$, it goes another way. The molecule $V(OH)_4$ does not exist, as the ion $V^{4+}$ is too small to fix $4$ groups $OH^-$. As a consequence, $V^{4+}$ gives another positive ion $VO^{2+}$ according to : 
$$V^{4+} +  H_2O \ce{->}  [VO]^{2+}+2H^+$$ Strangely enough, it looks as if the non-existent $V(OH)_4$ behaves like a basic hydroxide and gets dissociated according to : $$V(OH)_4\ce{->}[VO]^{2+}+ 2 OH^–$$
If $Z=5$, the ion $M^{5+}$ can be hydrolyzed according to $$M^{5+} + 3 H_2O \ce{->}  [MO_3]^{-}+6H^+$$$$M^{5+} + 4 H_2O \ce{->}  [MO_4]^{3-}+8H^+$$
But with Vanadium $V$, the ion $V^{5+}$ may be hydrolyzed  according to :$$V^{5+} + 2 H_2O \ce{->}  [VO_2]^{+}+4H^+$$$$V^{5+} + 3 H_2O \ce{->}  [VO_3]^{-}+6H^+$$The second reaction is favored at high pH.

This theoretical development is taken from General Chemistry, by Linus Pauling, W. F. Freemann and Co., San Francisco, 1953, Chapter XXI.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, vanadium cannot exist as a 4+ or 5+ ion except as part of a covalently bound species such as $\ce{VO^{2+}}$ or $\ce{VO2^+}$.  However, its heavier congeners niobium and tantalum form minerals whose structure indicates at least partial ionic bonding in the +5 oxidation state.  One such mineral is [Schiavinatoite](https://www.mindat.org/min-7110.html), a niobium-tantalum borate in which the niobium or tantalum (in the +5 oxidation state) has a high coordinate number (8) with all neighbors at essentially equal distances, which indicates a strong ionic contribution to the bonding.  The mindat.org site referenced above gives an original reference [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6td76.jpg), accessible [here](https://rruff.info/rruff_1.0/uploads/EJM13_159.pdf).

[image]

(Illustration from [mindat.org](https://www.mindat.org/min-7110.html). Blue = Nb/Ta, pink = B, red = O.)

Reference

1.
Demartin, F., Diella, V., Gramaccioli, C. M., Pezzotta, F. (2001) "Schiavinatoite, (Nb,Ta)BO4, the Nb analogue of behierite."  European Journal of Mineralogy: 13: 159-165.